# Using multiple ORs inside a query with one or more ANDs

Tags: php, mysql, operators, conditional-statements

I'm having a question concerning a mysql query.

What I want to achieve is the to write a query that says:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 = 'something' AND Col2 = 'something' AND 
         ( Col3 = 'Something' OR Col3 = 'Something');
```

So it looks the same as you whould use conditional statements in php: (notice the braces around the or ;) )

```
if ( $i == 'something' and ($k == 'something' || $k == 'something') ){
//Do something
}
```

or maybe there is another/better way to do that?

(**EDIT**)
I know now that the query is correct. Thank you for confirming that to me. Below is part of the query that keeps failing.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Condition1 = 'something'
AND(
 Enddate = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) 
OR 
 Enddate = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)) 
)
```

Probably something obvious but I can't seem to find it.

(**SOLVED**)

Hey sorry for the question.
I just figured out that the query mist a closing brace somewhere just after the above code.

Comment: what is the problem you face then? your query looks fine.

Comment: Beside from having the wrong case for the 2nd col3 this looks valid. What is your question anyway?

Comment: whats is the question? did you try your query? I think it's works

Comment: You're assigning in `if` condition, that must be `if($i == "somethign" and ($k == "something" || $k == "something")){}`

Comment: what do you want to have? php code or query?

Comment: As i said in the question, I want something that is like the or between the braces. but i know now that that is the correct way of writing and therefor i edited the question with more info

Comment: sorry little copy and past error. Shouldnt be there.

Comment: @Controvi so what is the problem.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `OR` conditions, you can use `IN` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 = 'something1' AND 
      Col2 = 'something2' AND 
      Col3 IN('Something3','Something4');
```

Comment: this was also a solution on getting the query cleaner. thnks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Condition1 = 'something'
AND(
 Enddate = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) 
OR 
 Enddate = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)) 
)
```

no need for "as kuur"